# What version of Bullet Physics engine does the blender game engine use in 2.74?

Tags: game-engine

What version of Bullet Physics engine does the blender game engine use in 2.74?

I would like to know and I dont see listed anywhere and don't have Git on this computer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the commit notes which you can [read online](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/extern/bullet2/src/) the current bullet version is from svn revision 2719 from 26 Dec 2013 which appears to be 14 revisions after the bullet 2.82 update.

There are a few newer changes but they appear to be blender only updates.